# Using Boto3 Stubber as a context manager when calling custom functions

Tags: python, boto3, stubbing

I'm writing up some unit tests and we'd like to use boto.stub to mock out the aws responses.

In this case, the functions being tested is just pulling IP addresses bases on some input, using the boto3.

I've followed the boto docs for Stubber here: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html

```
    def test_ip_address_list(self):
        ec2 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('ec2')
        response = api_stub_result() #just returns the mocked up response. IP address is set to 10.10.0.10 as a test

        with Stubber(ec2) as stubber:
            #stubber.activate() #I've tried with and without calling activate()
            stubber.add_response('describe_instances', response, {})
            results = ip_addresses("prod") #returns a list of ip addresses using describe_instances

        print(results)
        assert ("10.10.0.10") in results
```

The when I run this I would expect the instance described in api_stub_result to be the only IP address returned, or at least be in the list of IP's.

Instead the function reached out to AWS and actually pulls down the data for our instances.

Comment: Coming to this fairly late, but it's possible that since you aren't matching the expected parameters that would trigger the stubber to return your specific response. Try invoking `describe_instances` directly from within the stubber to see if it triggers the response as expected. If so, then inspect your `ip_addresses` code path to see if it's injecting parameters into the request, and then either match them in your stub, or ignore them with `stub.ANY`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the stubber before calling the method you are testing. So after stubber.add_response add a line for activating the stubber:

`stubber.activate()`

And it should work as expected

Comment: Using a `Stubber` as a context manager handles activation/deactivation for you, so the OP's use of `with Stubber(ec2)...` obviates the need for an explicit call to activate.